# Theano Tensor remove element?

Tags: python, theano

I am currently trying to learn theano.

Is there a way to, for example, delete/add a row/column from an NxN tensor? The [subtensor](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.set_subtensor) functionality highlighted in the documentation only modifies elements, not remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sutensor allow to take part of tensor. It is set_subtensor and inc_subtensor that allow to modify part of them.

Theano support Python and NumPy indexing and advanced indexing. You can do what you want in many ways. Here is a simple one:

```
import theano, numpy
T = theano.tensor.matrix()
f = theano.function([T], T[[1, 2, 4]])
f(numpy.arange(25).reshape(5, 5))
```

So mostly, you can just pass a list with the index of rows that you want to keep. For colums, just use:

```
import theano, numpy
T = theano.tensor.matrix()
f = theano.function([T], T[:, [1, 2, 4]])
f(numpy.arange(25).reshape(5, 5))
```

To add rows, we support the same interface as numpy, so mostly, you can just build a new tensor by concatenating the part you want:

```
import theano, numpy
T = theano.tensor.matrix()
o = theano.tensor.concatenate([T[2], T[4], [100, 101, 102, 103, 104]])
f = theano.function([T], o)
f(numpy.arange(25).reshape(5, 5))
```

Comment: thank you for the concise answer, but why does this not work with a theano.tensor.vector()?

Comment: This can also work with vector(). But what error do you have? Without code and the error you have, it is very hard to tell you what is the problem. It is probably just a small detail that cause you problem.

Comment: ah i figured it out, the slicing of a vector can only return an element like T[3] not a smaller vector like T[1,2,3] like with matrix T[[1,2,3]]. thanks again